# Flag order in C

Tags: c, arguments, argv, getopt

So I have a question about flags and arguments in C from argv array.
When I enter a commant through terminal:
Example: `./main a b c -a`
It does not recognize that -a at the end but if I put it at the beginning of all arguments like: `./main -a a b c`
it will detect it.

I tried swapping it with if so it would be in the front of all argumetns, but after a swap it doesnt proceed. Something like ignoring the for loop after it. So it just swaps it and then ends the case. If anyone know what am I missing here I would be happy.

Code:

```
while ( (c = getopt(argc, argv, ":ahd:")) != -1) {
    switch (c) {
        case 'a': 
            if(strcmp(argv[argc-1], "-a") == 0){
                swap(&argv[argc-1], &argv[1]);
            }
            for(i = optind; i < argc; i++){
                for(j = optind; j < argc - 1; j++){
                    if(strcmp(argv[j], argv[j + 1]) > 0){
                        swap(&argv[j], &argv[j + 1]);
                    }
                }
            }

            for(z = optind; z < argc; z++){ 
                printf("%s\n", argv[z]);
            }
            printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
            break;
```

Comment: You're missing your code in the question so we can see what you're doing wrong? :)

Comment: What is the "it" you are referring to when you say "It does not recognize..."?

Comment: The problem is not whether the program arguments appear in the `argv` array -- they all do, in their order of appearance on the command line -- but rather what your program does with them.  We can't speak to what your program does when you've presented nothing of the program.  If you want help with code, we normally expect a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNU version of [`getopt()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt) allows for permutation of arguments so that all `-a` style options (that appear before a `--` option) will be processed, even if there are non-option arguments before them.

```
some_program -z abc def -b -- -w warning
```

The `-z` and `-b` options would be recognized by GNU `getopt()`, but the `-w` would be a non-option argument.

The POSIX version of [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) does not allow this; many non-GNU implementations of `getopt()` do not do this.  GNU knows that what they do is an extension; the permute behaviour can be turned of by setting `POSIXLY_CORRECT` in the environment.

If you want options to be recognized anywhere, use the GNU `getopt()` in your program.  If you want to use the local `getopt()` to remain portable, or can't afford to use GPL code in your programs, design your system to put options before non-option arguments.  Note that programs like `make` and the C compilers already have custom argument handling systems that allow the interleaving of options and non-option arguments — but you should follow POSIX coding guidelines ([Utility Conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)) for option handling unless you have a strong reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've fixed it by changing if sentence

```
if(strcmp(argv[optind-1], "-a") == 0){
            swap(&argv[optind-1], &argv[1]);
        }
```